# How to apply password protection when converting Html to PDF using EO.pdf?

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using EO.Pdf to convert my html text to pdf, i want to apply password protection on it, pdf file should not be opened without password.
EO.Pdf provides the option if i use PDFDocument object where i can pass .UserPassword to its object using following code, it works fine.
PdfDocumentSecurity security = new PdfDocumentSecurity("1234");

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(inputFileName, security);

//Set a new password "5678"
doc.Security.UserPassword = "5678";
```

but if i use the following as i have to convert html to pdf,

```
EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtml(download, pdfName,options);
```

And even if i pass username and password to the above argument "options", it does not work. Does anyone has solution?

Comment: Your question is not about iText so I removed the tag.

Comment: stackoverflow does not have eo.pdf tag and neither i can create it so i assumed may be itext developers know about it.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You hijacked an unrelated tag of a competing product and that is not a polite thing to do. Ask the developers of eo.pdf (https://essentialobjects.com/ContactUs.aspx) to create the tag.

Comment: I think hijack is quite a serious word and if you have the solution please post below.

Comment: I agree that hijack is a serious word and I do not use it lightly. If you have a better word, please post below.